# Is there a list of all places in SF config where UI error messages can be defined?

Tags: error, error-messages, ui

When creating an Account I encountered an error message:

[image]

Looks like a custom message but I searched over every possible place I know where custom error messages can be created and didn't find it. These places were:

- Duplicate rules
- Validation rules
- Account triggers (looking for addError() method)

Probably I just don't know about every possibility, so the question is:

**Is there a list of possible places where UI error messages can be defined?**

And if not - could someone who knows it, provide such a list?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should take the help of a tool like 'Eclipse' or 'VS Code' to be able to search across all the metadata objects to find this error string "A Record with.....". It could be a custom label, so try searching for this in the custom labels (Setup->Custom Labels). Otherwise try to put a debug on your user and check the debug log where this is coming from to know the exact truth.

There is no such centralized place of errors in general. In programming practice we use custom labels to store such error messages and reference that label in the apex or lightning code.